# Is there a way to see render progress when rendering from the command line?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, command-line

I'm using google colab to render my projects, and, due to not being able to set up x via ssh (or ssh at all), I'm stuck to rendering with command-line. I do get updates on how much was rendered already, but I can't see the preview of the render as if I'm rendering locally, so to make sure I don't have to adjust samples etc. I have to wait. Is there a way to make blender save the file once every tile/sample/minute etc. (preferrably without progressive rendering)?

Comment: One thing you can try is rendering to *OpenEXR* and enable *save buffers*, which stores each render bracket (aka tile) directly to the file after it's finished.

Comment: Didn't work for blender2.79, is that 2.8-specific?

Comment: `blender -b scene.blend -o scene -f 1`; format: `OpenEXR`, RGBA Float (Full) ZIP; `save buffers`, `placeholders`, `cache result` enabled - doesn't work for me. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Sorry, can't test it since I don't have access to 2.79 anymore... Consider using 2.8x which should speed up your renders anyway.

Comment: I'm using 2.8 on google colab, the problem is that it's almost impossible to use it on my local machine (RPI4)

Comment: Same setup did not work on google colab (blender2.82) as well.